# Is it standard to use a hyperlink (anchor tag) within a label tag?

Tags: html, hyperlink, label

Is it standard to use a hyperlink (anchor tag) within a label tag?

```
<label for="ContentPlaceHolder1">
   <a href="~/address"> Link Text and Label Name </a>
</label>
```

Comment: What do you mean by standard? You can validate the markup and see.

Comment: I would have thought this was ill-advised (if not entirely invalid), since the `label` element has an interactive component and can be clicked on.

Comment: The HTML5 spec says "The activation behavior of a label element for events targeted at interactive content descendants of a label element, and any descendants of those interactive content descendants, must be to do nothing."

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is *valid* to have an anchor inside a label — in HTML 4.01 as well as HTML5.

You can try out the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) to quickly check if your markup is valid.

Whether it makes sense is another question. It is probably ok to have a link alongside with some non-link-text inside a label, but a label consisting of a single link probably won't be a great user experience.